# Twitter typeahead not showing results where they start with the same word

Tags: javascript, twitter-typeahead

I'm using twitter typeahead to provide a drop down of results being returned from a webservice . I'm finding that its only displaying a subset of these results; apparently its suppressing any one that starts with the same first word.

```
    var $termInput = $("#someId");
    var lookup = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer:  Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
                url:/search/ + "%QUERY",
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    lookup.initialize();

    $termInput.typeahead(
        { hint: true, highlight: true },
        {
            source: lookup,
            name: 'cases',
            displayKey: 'id',
            valueKey: 'id',
            templates: {
                empty: "<div class='omniboxresult nomatch'>No matching cases found</div>",
                suggestion: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);


                    return "<div class='omniboxresult'><div class='caseName'>" + "hi " +data.text + "</div></div>";
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Html is:

```
<input type=text" class="form-control" id="someId" value="" data-provider="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
```

Using the network tab I know that my webservice is returning (when I enter "Euro"):

```
[{"id":"1991003933","level":0,"text":"EUROPEAN COMMUNITY"},
{"id":"1971004125","level":0,"text":"EUROPEAN ECONOMIC COMMUNITY"},
{"id":"2011007673","level":0,"text":"EUROPEAN UNION"},
{"id":"2011000582","level":0,"text":"EUROPEAN UNION"}]
```

But I only get the following in my output:

[image]

If I were to enter "e" I get more results, e.g. "English" which are not suppressed (but I still only get one result that starts with "EUROPEAN"

Why is this happening and how can I get it to display all results it receives?

Comment: This was ultimately a bug in typeahead. Note that there are two versions of typeahead. The original and abandoned https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ and the maintained one that has the bug fix https://typeahead.js.org/. The first abandoned one has this bug and probably will forever

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem in my project when I wanted to show autocomplete suggestions for names. I wanted to show autocomplete suggestions for first names, then first and last names. My implementation ends up looking like this:

`Sar` = `Sara, Sarah, Saralou, Sarchenko, Sargent`

`Sarah[space]` = `Sarah, Sarah Majercik, Sarah Maddux, Sarah Zarek, Sarah Anderson`

Not perfect, as I'd prefer once someone does a space `Sarah` is no longer shown, but I haven't figured that out yet. My solution was to prepend my data set with all the unique first and last names in alphabetical order. I was using the `prefetch` but I think `remote` also has the `filter` method available:

```
var lookup = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer:  Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
            url:/search/ + "%QUERY",
            filter: function(list) {
                var uniques = [];
                // parse out unique names

                // my list was literally a list of first and last names so I concat them, you'll likely need to do a bit more work here
                return uniqes.concat(list); 
            },
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
```

Using this your results will look like:

`EURO` = `EUROPEAN, EUROPEAN COMMUNITY, EUROPEAN ECONOMIC COMMUNITY, EUROPEAN UNION`

Hope this helps.